# Questions in Sybase lag and over by concept

Tags: sybase

I have table like this below in my sybase database

```
ID,Col1,Col2
1,100,300
2,300, 400
3,400,500
4,900,1000.
```

I want result like this below only in sybase.

```
1,100,500 --- cross interrow checking the values
2,900,1000.
```

Answer (score 0):

SInce you did not specify which database you're using, I'm assuming your using Sybase ASE (rather than Sybase IQ or Sybase SQL Anywhere, which do support lag/lead etc.)

Also it's not quite clear what you want since you have not defined how the relation between the various rows and columns should be interpreted. But I'm guessing you're essentially hinting at a dependency graph between Col2->Col1.

In ASE, you'll need to write this as a multi-step, loop-based algorithm whereby you determine the dependency graph. Since you don't know how many levels deep this will run, you need a loop rather than a self-join. You need to keep track of the result in a temporary table. 
Can't go further here... but that's the sort of approach you'll need.